# How many days does a month contain for the US customs and border protection when indicating "Out 5 months, 29 days." upon reentry?

Tags: usa, greencard

How many days does a month contain for the US customs and border protection when indicating "Out 5 months, 29 days." upon reentry on the passport of a US lawful permanent resident?

Example from https://lawandborder.com/guide-to-reentry-permits/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200820001830/https://lawandborder.com/guide-to-reentry-permits/)):

[image]

> Out 5 months, 29 days.

Comment: Perhaps "5 months" simply means the period of time from the starting date until the same day of the month 5 months later, so it could be a different number of days depending on the exact months.

Comment: Why does this matter? The critical time periods are stated in months, not days.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan sometimes stated in days, since months are unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How many days does a month contain?

Different months contain different numbers of days.  Five months plus 29 days can be anywhere from 179 days to 182 days.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping that the US customs and border protection agents followed some guidelines. But perhaps you are correct.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt if you look online for six-month admission stamps you'll see that the "until" date is obtained by adding six months to the date of entry and subtracting one day.  But in any event it doesn't matter what the officer writes in the passport, which could be the result of a miscalculation.  What matters are the actual dates of departure and return.